# How to decide a closed Top/PL manifold is a boundary?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

For a closed smooth manifold, we can use the Stiefel-Whitney number of the manifold to decide it is boundary or not.

For a closed topology or PL manifold, how to decide it is a boundary of compact Top/PL manifold?

As far as I know,  the Top/PL cobordism ring is a litter complex. So I guess they may not have simple way as in the smooth case to decide which closed Top/PL manifold is boundary. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know if it completely answers your question, but you may be interested in Brumfiel, Madsen, and Milgram, ["PL characteristic classes and cobordism."](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970878)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, since I can't find the exactly answer in Madsen's work, then I pose the question here.